# Sparql 1.0 not bound count on ARC2

Tags: sparql

I'am trying to analyse some graph for a customer. (i'am using ARC2 with sparql 1.0 specs)

He wants to be sure that some fields are filled by his data provider.

To do this I want to count the subjects having unbound elements and bound elements subjects:

Here is my query:

```
SELECT count(?unbound) as ?unboundCount count(?s) as ?bound
WHERE {   
    ?s <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/source> ?o .                                                      
    OPTIONAL { ?unbound <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/source>  ?y } .
    FILTER(!BOUND(?y) )
}
```

It returns 0 for both ?bound and ?unboundcount. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have any triples with a `dc11:source` predicate? This is a very strange query -- the optional has no variable to join with the outer block.

Comment: Yes I checked, there are triples with dc:source predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT count(?unbound) as ?unboundCount count(?s) as ?bound
WHERE {
    # Things with a source 
    { 
      ?s <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/source> ?o
    }
    UNION
    # Things without a source
    { 
      ?unbound a ?type # match everything?      
      OPTIONAL { ?unbound <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/source>  ?y } .
      FILTER(!BOUND(?y))
    }
}
```

The first bit of the union is obvious enough. For the second bit -- things without a source -- we need to find 'everything' (or at least things of interest), then keep only those subjects without a source. `?s a ?type` is a reasonable first stab at finding everything, but you may have a better way of identifying the items of interest in your dataset.

Comment: Strange I tried your query if i use it as you gave me I have a correct bound value and if swap the two union blocks #Things without a source in first and # Thing with a source in second, I get only the unbounds values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ARC2 can't manage multiples count on such a query.

I succeed by making two separates query:

```
# The unbound query
SELECT count(?unbound) as ?unboundCount
WHERE {   
    ?unbound <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/source> ?o .                                                      
    OPTIONAL { ?unbound <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/source>  ?y } .
    FILTER(!BOUND(?y) )
}
# The bound query
SELECT count(?s) as ?boundCount
WHERE {   
    ?s <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/source> ?o .                                                      
}
```

We are far from an elegant answer but it seems this is the only way to go with ARC2